# Optimizing the SQLite database as source data for R scripts

Tags: r, database, sqlite, etl

I have an application written in `R Shiny` that supports a large number of `csv's` (and 3 new ones are added every day). These files have a structure that is quite unpleasant to handle, so I decided to create a `database` and store the data in the target form there.
So when a new file appears, it goes through the `ETL process` (extract from `csv`, transformation to the target structure and loading into `db`).
Unfortunately, due to administrative limitations, I only have the `SQLite engine` at my disposal.
At the beginning, the database worked great, but after loading a larger data set into it (the `.db` file is about `5GB`), performance problems began to appear.
First things first. I have 3 files, so I created 3 tables (separate for each file type). Each of them has an identical structure, differing only in the source of data.
The tables are called:

- `maritime_transport`
- `railway_transport`
- `air_transport`

And they have the following structure:

- `Datetime text NOT NULL` - exact time stamp of the transaction
- `Day text` - the day of the transaction determined on the basis of Datetime (to facilitate subsequent aggregation)
- `Week text` - a week of transactions determined on the basis of Datetime, in the form of the last day of the week (to facilitate subsequent aggregation)
- `Month text` - the month of the transaction determined on the basis of Datetime, in the form of the last day of the month (to facilitate subsequent aggregation)
- `Year text` - the year of the transaction determined on the basis of Datetime, in the form of the last day of the year (to facilitate subsequent aggregation)
- `From text` - exporter
- `To text` - importer
- `Value numeric` - transaction value
  Each table has approximately 20 million rows.

I have indexes set up on the `Day` columns in each of the above tables.
And this is my source data.

The first additional layer contains balances for each company: `sum(export - import)` - separately for each table.

Additionally, it needs daily, weekly, monthly and annual aggregation for each type (i.e. for `exporter-importer` pairs and for the balance sheets of each company).

What's the best way to solve this problem to maximize application performance?

My first idea was to create `views`:

- for balance sheets for each contractor
- individual aggregates (day, week, month, year) for the exporter-importer relationship
- individual aggregates (day, week, month, year) per contractor
  But this solution worked well for small data sets or multi-million tables, there was a problem with the performance of views, let alone the view from views (aggregation by dates for balance sheets).

[image]

I am also wondering whether to treat db only as a data storage and not perform any calculations there. For example, if a new data file appears, should it be loaded and then any aggregation performed in the application.
Another option considered is to convert the views into physical tables and force updates of these tables each time new data appears (e.g. if a new day appears in a given month, the monthly aggregate currently located in the `db` is deleted, the `R script` recalculates the aggregate for a given month and loads it into db).

Or are there any methods to optimize `SQLite` apart from indexing which didn't help much?

Thank you very much for all your advice and comments!

Comment: Views are not likely to improve performance, but I suspect that creating an index(es) would be useful and helpful. Hope you do that depends on your typical queries. (I wonder if `duckdb` might be a faster file-based SQL engine.) This question belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: should I remove that topic here and move to dba.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: At a minimum, while "shiny" provided some context, your problem is entirely data-driven, so I think [tag:shiny] is a distraction. I don't know that you can move the question yourself short of "delete and repost". No matter where your question is posted, though, it works help to see your typical query(ies) (actual SQL code) in order to inform the "index" question.

Comment: One thing that might be slowing you down a little is storage of the timestamp as a string. If it were instead numeric (typically epoch seconds), if that is used in filters then many queries would likely be a bit faster.

Comment: You reference `sum(export - import)` but don't list those columns, is that an oversight, or do you have to calculate `export` and `import` from the other values?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the numeric timestamp.
When it comes to `sum(export - import)`, it is a mental shortcut, because in both cases it is about the `Value` column. This sum is obtained using, e.g. for monthly aggregation:

`With tmp as (
    SELECT Month, From Company, Value FROM maritime_transport UNION ALL
    SELECT Month, To Company, -Value FROM maritime_transport
)
SELECT Month, Company, Sum(Value) Value 
FROM tmp
GROUP BY Month, Company`

Comment: Okay, we're getting closer ... I'm not a (formal) DBA, but well-trained SQL admins can take queries like that to help inform what index(es) should be defined. Realize that indexes usually speed up reads, often slow down writes, and I think in this case you're much more interested in speeding up the reads, so it's heading in the right direction. It seems possible that some of your aggregation in SQL may be improved, though that might be a different question. (I also find that some SQL aggregation can be done faster in R ... not all the time, but possible.)

Comment: I have indexes set up on the `Day` columns in each of 3 main tables. Does it make sense to create an index for each of the columns responsible for the aggregation level? What I mean here, apart from Day, is also Week, Month, Year

Comment: Indexes can (and sometimes should) be multi-column indexes. You can have multiple indexes (at a storage-size cost).

Comment: A reasonable intro to indexes in SQLite is https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/. It doesn't tell you what you need here, but I think with some experimentation (and `explain query plan select ...`) and some benchmarking you should be able to find some improvements.